# Is there any more efficient way of getting web elements' css properties than using selenium?

Tags: python, jquery, css, selenium, automated-tests

In my code, I need to get the CSS properties of **a large number** of web elements,
currently I'm using selenium and the code is like:

```
    ... 
    node = browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_to_node)
    return {k: node.value_of_css_property(k)
            for k in ('color', 'font-family', 'font-size', 'font-weight', 'letter-spacing')}
```

However, it is very slow, it took around **1 minute** to query these CSS properties for *10k* nodes.
The reason why it is so slow is, the function of `value_of_css_property` is based on the communication with the server. The frequent calls of `request` is too expensive.

Is there any better method or tool for solving this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Few variants:

- use javascript inside the browser and extract the results
- Get raw HTML and analyse it